# Linux OpenVPN tap routing works for single IPs but not for all traffic

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

I'm trying to get a home VPN setup before I travel for the holidays.

I have an OpenVPN server using a TAP setup running successfully and I'm able to connect to it with a client.

However I'm having issues routing the client traffic through it.

The `redirect-gateway` option isn't working for me. For now, I'm giving up on that and trying to set up my routes manually.

My approach has been to first run a DHCP client (dhcpcd) against the tap interface and then attempt to add routes by hand.

```
# dhcpcd tap0
dhcpcd-9.4.1 starting
...
tap0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.137
tap0: probing address 192.168.1.137/24
tap0: leased 192.168.1.137 for 86400 seconds
tap0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
forked to background, child pid 11185
```

The routes the DHCP client sets up work fine for internal IPs. I'm able to ping/ssh computers on my home network. I am testing this from a tethered cell connection.

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.149.13 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.149.193 metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev tap0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.137 metric 1052
192.168.149.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.149.193 metric 600

# ping 192.168.1.136 # another IP on my network
PING 192.168.1.136 (192.168.1.136) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.136: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=104 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.136: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=83.5 ms
...
```

If I manually add IP routes for internet hosts using my home network's gateway IP, I am able to access those through OpenVPN.

(note, 175.55.55.55 is supposed to be my tethered cell connection, and 72.33.33.33 is meant to be my home IP)

```
# curl -4 https://icanhazip.com
175.55.55.55

# host -t a icanhazip.com
icanhazip.com has address 104.18.115.97
icanhazip.com has address 104.18.114.97

# ip route add 104.18.115.97 via 192.168.1.1
# ip route add 104.18.114.97 via 192.168.1.1

# curl -4 https://icanhazip.com
72.33.33.33
```

The problem is that I don't know how to generalize this to all traffic.

I have tried to add catchall routes to pass traffic over the VPN:

```
# ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.1.1 dev tap0
# ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.1.1 dev tap0
```

When I try to hit icanhazip.com again, it times out and the OpenVPN client logs say:

```
2022-12-15 15:27:38 us=127602 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]72.33.33.33:2445
2022-12-15 15:27:38 us=122602 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]72.33.33.33:2445
2022-12-15 15:27:38 us=147702 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]72.33.33.33:2445
```

I can provide the log or the configurations from the client (or the server) if that would help, but I think this is likely more of a routing issue.

Comment: You should add a `72.33.33.33 via 192.168.149.13 dev wlan0` route. If you have the "dynamic issue", consider adding the `tap0` routes to another route table and make different traffics (e.g., encapsulated VPN traffics and all other traffics) look up different route table by using ip rules.

Comment: @TomYan Oh, excellent, that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, duh.

@TomYan helped me figure it out.

The OpenVPN client was communicating with the OpenVPN server through the `wlan0` device.

When I overrode the `wlan0` route as the default (or effectively default, using `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` addresses) and tried to send all the traffic through the vpn `tap0` device, that included the OpenVPN traffic too.

The "recursive routing" message was indeed correct.

If I had been using TCP, I probably would've noticed the issue sooner as the connection would've just timed out as soon as I put those routes there.

The solution is to explicitly add a single address route that permits the OpenVPN client to still reach the server.

So immediately after DHCP the routes have:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.149.13 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.149.193 metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev tap0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.137 metric 1052
192.168.149.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.149.193 metric 600
```

My OpenVPN server address is `72.33.33.33`, so I'll manually add a route to it through the wlan0 gateway mentioned in the default above:

```
# ip route add 72.33.33.33 via 192.168.149.13 dev wlan0
```

And now my two catchall routes will work:

```
# ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.1.1 dev tap0
# ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.1.1 dev tap0
# curl -4 https://icanhazip.com
73.33.33.33
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.